# Plotting the output of integrate.quad with an np.linspace array

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, physics

I am trying to plot an integrated function of E with the range of values of E. I cannot figure out how to make the output of the integrate.quad function compatible with the range of E.

This is the code that I have been using

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as phys
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
E = np.linspace(0, 12, 10000)
fermi = 4.5
kT = 0.04
dfdE = np.exp((E-fermi)/(kT))/((np.exp((E-fermi)/(kT)) + 1)**2) * 1/(kT)
t = 1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(0-0.5)*3))) +  1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(1-0.5)*3)))+  1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(2-0.5)*3)))+ 1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(3-0.5)*3)))+ 1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(4-0.5)*3)))+ 1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(5-0.5)*3)))+ 1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(6-0.5)*3))) -2

f = dfdE*t-2

def f_integral(E):
    return f


result_f = integrate.quad_vec(f_integral, fermi-1.5, fermi+1.5 )
print(result_f)



plt.plot(E,result_f)
```

This is the error that is occurring:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\OneDrive\Documents\BSc_Project\Plot.py:29 in <module>
    plt.plot(E,result_f)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2757 in plot
    return gca().plot(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1632 in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:312 in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:498 in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (2,)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the error means that you're trying to plot x (with 10000 values) and y that only has 2 values.

Comment: You did `print(result_f)`.  You didn't show it.  Did you look at it yourself?  Understand what it showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `result_f` is a tuple, you need to slice it with `[0]` before calling [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

```
plt.plot(E, result_f[0]) # <- we slice here
```

[image]